# to find a function for dominated convergence theorem

Tags: measure-theory

for which value of x$\in $$\mathbb{R}$ is$ \int^\infty_0 $$e^{-t}t^{x-1}$dt is integrable?

answer: I know  that I have to solve it from dominated convergence theorem but how I can define a  good dominated function?

Comment: Do you mean what value of $t$ or do you want to integrate with respect to $t$?

Comment: Dominated convergence is not really useful here, since it normally is used to pass from convergence a.e. to convergence in $L^p$.

Comment: sorry I mean integral with respect to t

Answer (score 2):

This is the Gamma function $\Gamma$. Notice that

$$e^{-t}t^{x-1}=_\infty o\left(\frac1{t^2}\right)$$
so the integral
$$\int_1^\infty  e^{-t}t^{x-1}dt$$
exists for all $x$ and we have
$$e^{-t}t^{x-1}\sim_0 \frac{1}{t^{1-x}}\in L^1(0,1)\iff 1-x<1\iff x>0$$

so we find that $\Gamma(x)$ is defined for $x>0$.

Comment: is this same? if integral is with respect to t

Answer (score 0):

For the values of $x$ for which the integral exists, there are two places for problems (and no need for the big theorem):

1. Around $\infty$: there is no problem thanks to the $\exp $ term. The integrand $f(x)$ is $>0$ and such as $\exp(x/2) f(x)$ is bounded.
2. Around 0: you can drop the $\exp$ term as it has a limit. Then you are left with some integral you should know pretty well.